¿Cómo cambiar imagen de JLabel y luego moverlo en la misma acción?
Al utilizar las teclas WASD o las direccionales las variables que guardan la posición del jugador en X Y cambiaran dependiendo a donde se dirija, luego se llamara al void jugadorSprite para cambiar la imagen siguiendo una secuencia como de movimiento y por ultimo desplazar el JLabel del jugador a las nuevas ubicaciones X Y.
El problema es que al parecer si cambias la imagen de por ejemplo un JLabel este volverá a su posición de origen cuando se creo o donde se colocó en el editor además si por ejemplo presionas S para ir hacia abajo y para primero cambiar la imagen y después moverlo no hace nada sin embargó sí se guardan las variables X Y
Les dejo un ejemplo al presionar la tecla S para ir hacia abajo, la pagina no me dejo agregar más partes del código pero estos son los esenciales:
// jugador mapa
public int posX = 100,posY = 100, mouseX,mouseY;
// Sprites
public String direccionSprite = "down-", rutaSprite;
public int estadoSprite = 0; // 0 y 2 = idle // 1 = walk right leg // 3 = walk left leg    
public Icon spriteJugador;

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyChar() == 's' || e.getKeyChar() == 'S'){
        if(jugadorHitbox.getX()+jugadorHitbox.getWidth()<=muro.getX() || jugadorHitbox.getX()>=muro.getX()+muro.getWidth()){
            posY+=10;
        }
        else{
            if(jugadorHitbox.getY()+10<=muro.getY()-jugadorHitbox.getHeight() || jugadorHitbox.getY()>=muro.getY()){
                posY+=10;
            }
            else{
            }
        }
        jugadorSprite(estadoSprite+1,"down-","Greg"); // estado del sprite // dirección del jugador // Personaje          
    }
 jugador.setLocation(posX,posY); }

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}

public void jugadorSprite(int estadoSpr, String direccion, String chara){
    if(estadoSpr>3 || !direccion.equals(direccionSprite)){estadoSpr = 0;}
    estadoSprite = estadoSpr;
    direccionSprite = direccion;
    String estado = "";
    switch(estadoSprite){
        case 0: estado = "idle-"; break;
        case 1: estado = "walk1-"; break;
        case 2: estado = "idle-"; break;
        case 3: estado = "walk2-"; break;
    }
    rutaSprite = "/char.sprites/".concat(chara).concat("/").concat(estado).concat(direccion).concat(chara).concat(".png");
    spriteJugador = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(rutaSprite));
    jugador.setIcon(spriteJugador);
    // No es necesario: lblCordenadas.setText("Cordenadas: X="+String.valueOf(posX)+" Y="+String.valueOf(posY));
    jugador.setLocation(posX,posY);
    jugador.repaint();
}


Como los repintados son dependientes de la plataforma, te recomiendo usar SwingUtilities.invokeLater para que se encargue de manejar la asincronicidad por tí y haga el pintado cuando se hayan hecho los cálculos pertinentes
